# How to throttle netty server with slow client?

Tags: clojure, netty, riemann

In order to prevent OOME in a [riemann](http://riemann.io) server when clients do not read ACKs properly, I have implemented [some logic](https://github.com/riemann/riemann/blob/master/src/riemann/transport/tcp.clj#L69) to close the channel when it becomes unwritable, under the assumption this is caused by client not reading/ACKing packets quickly enough.

However, this also closes the channel when sending large-ish query results, probably because the server tries to write the result faster than it can be sent through TCP. Out of the top of my head, I would think the best way to handle this situation would be to set some timeout on writing, using a [WriteTimeoutHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/WriteTimeoutHandler.html).

Is there some standard pattern known in netty to handle that case?

Comment: Looks like this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862613/throttling-websockets-with-netty-socketio-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would stop writing once `Channel.isWritable()` returns false and start again once it returns true again. You can be notified by the update of this by overriding `ChannelInboundHandler.channelWritabilityChanged(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, that's something I had in mind but this seems quite complicated in this particular case as I need to handle some logic to know what kind of responses are not written. Is there a way to discard responses in the output buffer? In the end I am afraid there is no practical solution to what I want to do...